# how to initilize an array object in android?

Tags: android

I have a class `MenuDesc`, when I tried to initialize, it's giving `nullpointerexception error`.

```
public static class SlideMenuAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<SlideMenu.SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc> {
static class MenuDesc {
    public int icon;
    public String label;
}
}

SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[] items = new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[5];
//fill the menu-items here
items[0].label="uday";
items[1].label="ravi";
items[2].label="rahul";
```

i'm getting nullpointer error.

Comment: I don't see a constructor call there.

Answer (score 3):

In Java or Android you have to instantiate the object.

```
items[0] = new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc();
```

For your case you need loop before assignment which initializes the object

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    items[i] = new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc();
```

Comment: I guess it now solves the issue for you.. it was a typing error.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is:

```
public static class SlideMenuAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<SlideMenu.SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc> {
    static class MenuDesc {
        public int icon;
        public String label;
        MenuDesc(final String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
    }
}

SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[] items = new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc[] {
    new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc("uday"),
    new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc("ravi"),
    new SlideMenuAdapter.MenuDesc("rahul")
};
```